# Can a 40 hp ultralight trike with a 15 m wing take off with simple (homebuilt) tube floats?

Tags: aircraft-design, takeoff

There seem to be no floats manufactured for 103 trikes- under 500 pounds including gas and pilot. Seems like they could be smaller and lighter than existing ones.
I am considering fabricating floats primarily for a possible emergency engine out landing along a rocky coast.  Being able to take off would be great, but secondary.  (I would prefer to not turn turtle and sink instantly). I would be landing at about 25 mph

Can a 40 hp trike with a 15 m wing take off with simple tube floats or are stepped hard shell stepped floats necessary?

Comment: Define "tube floats". There are tubes made out of soft rubber, like tire tubes, and there are floats made out of aluminium but shaped like tubes, used in some types of inland watercraft. ?? Pictures of what you mean would be very helpful. 8)

Comment: If it is not required to *take off* from the water and it is only for *emergency landing* then why would you want to deal with the  drag the tubes produce? I'd say that the primary aim is not to loose the trike by sinking. So I'd use (one or two) inflatable life wests mounted on the trike that you can use after landing to make it float.

Comment: The floats would be hard shell fiberglass similar to a paddle board. I am wondering if floats on a weight shift trike (with the weight hanging freely below the wing ) would be "stuck" to the water and need the step on the float.